# Cannot add distance between droplist and its content that overlaps some other elements

Tags: html, css

I cannot add distance between `About us` and a navigation tab without cursor failing to reach the tab when it hovers over the `About us` panel.

I tried appending `margin-top:;` and `margin-bottom:;` but did not pay off.
Also, I deliberately did not remove `<hr>` tags, because it is a must to keep them and I hunched they could have prevented my intention from happening.

```css
.dropdown {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .list {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .dropcontent {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.dropdown .dropcontent a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="list">About us</a>
    <div class="dropcontent">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Add `top: 40px;` to `.dropdown .dropcontent`

Comment: Isn't that kind of perilous to use `top:;`? I mean, I find it to be the last resort I wish to come up with.

Comment: You can also use margins and you don't need any positioning stuff if you change the structure a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `position: absolute` and `top: 47px` to the `.dropcontain`

```css
.dropdown {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .list {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .dropcontent {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
}

.dropdown .dropcontent a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="list">About us</a>
    <div class="dropcontent">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```